# Finding the IP address and port of local SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) documentation and I am not not sure what my IP address and port number of my local SQL Server is. I enabled TCP/IP for ip4 for SQL Server Express, and restarted the service in SQL Server Configuration Manager. I can ping my local IP which is 127.0.0.1 but I don't know my port number.

Comment: You need to right-click on the TCP/IP, go to Properties and then IP Addresses tab. Scroll down and look for TCP Dynamic Ports

Comment: By default SQL Server runs on port 1433, so you unless you changed it, that'll be what it is. As for 127.0.0.1 that IP is the loopback IP, it will always point back to the **current** local machine.

Comment: @Abhishek I tried putting 1433 for dynamic port and regular port and it does not seem to work. I'm trying to use it as a datasource for my local grafana. This is the error message, "
Unable to open tcp connection with host '127.0.0.1:1433': dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1433: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `IP` address it's your machine `IP` address.

To get the ports which the server listening on run this query:

```
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on', N'any', NULL, NULL, N'asc' 
GO
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "Msg 22004, Level 12, State 1, Line 2
Error executing extended stored procedure: Invalid Parameter Type"

Comment: @user9864738 add `N` before `'any'`